# Openlayers zoomToExtent from array of coordinates

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a dropdown list. On Selection, it will request extent of selected property to database (PostgreSQL). I am using PHP for server-side processing.

At client-side on console log gives extent output result (variable `res`):

```
[74.3965356273929, 75.2484319931094, 35.6450698628058, 34.776235256942]
```

Also I am sure that coordinates are float and not string using `parseFloat()` function. later I am  passing that variable to `OpenLayers.Bounds`.

```
    var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(res);
    map.zoomToExtent(extent);
```

`OpenLayers.Bounds` gives following output:

```
OpenLayers.Bounds.OpenLayers.Class.initialize {left: 74.396535627393, bottom: 75.248431993109, right: 35.645069862806, top: 34.776235256942, left: null…}
```

Which is I guess correct. But Openlayers is not zooming to the provided extent and it is zooming to maximum zoom level at current map view only.

Comment: What projection is your map in? is it web Mercator(EPSG:3857)?

Comment: its just a guess, but can you try to switch the order of the coordinates? like this: 34.776235256942, 74.3965356273929,  35.6450698628058, 75.2484319931094

Comment: and is the left parameter really null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of attributes when you create an `OpenLayers.Bounds` object, you have to order the arguments like this: minx, miny, maxx, maxy.

See the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KfkwV/2/

Comment: That is the answer. worked like charm...